# Can a Python Executable create files?

Tags: python, download, executable

I converted my Python code into an executable using pyinstaller but part of my project involves printing the result onto a text document, stored on the computer. However this same code doesn't work once in the executable. I separately also tried to get it to just create files using the

```
with open(f'{random.random()}.txt', 'x') as sys.stdout:
    print(encmsg)
```

option and using a random num generator to create new file names so it doesn't overlap. Still didn't create anything.

In Summary,
What code, when running through an executable file, will download the string it produces onto a text file onto the computer SOMEWHERE.

Thank you.

The relevant code is:

```
string = '1219151'

with open(f'{random.random()}.txt', 'x') as sys.stdout:
      print(string)
```

That is it. It's in an executable, but doesn't produce the txt file anywhere.
I am on Windows 10.

Comment: Could use more details? Do you have a Minimal Working Example? Are you on windows or linux? In general, yes, python (like any turing complete language) is capable of doing any task on a computer.

Comment: An executable can create files in the same way as a script. The path is relative and therefore may point to the wrong destination.

Comment: Anyway I can point it in any relevant direction?

Comment: Filenames are relative to the user's current directory, not the directory containing the executable. If you want the file to be in a specific directory, put the directory in the code.